# Where can I find launch trajectory data of the space shuttle?

Tags: launch, space-shuttle

I am trying to mathematically model the launch of the space shuttle (up to 120km altitude) from Cape Canaveral Florida. It would be really handy if I could check my calculations with some real launch data. However after some googling I couldn't really find anything except for the real basics. What I am looking for (per 20 seconds or so):

- Altitude
- Velocity
- Acceleration
- Angle of attack
- Pitch angle
- Throttle settings

The first three I could find [here](https://education.ti.com/~/media/4113B908B22F4F5085BE8319260A02B0). Does anybody know where I could get the other data? For the velocity and the acceleration it would also be interesting to see them split up between X & Z direction.

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer (throttle settings):

Throttle settings varied per flight, and NASA quit publishing these Mission Reports a long time ago. But here are some numbers to get you started, from STS-81 (the last one I could find online).

[image]

For the 3-G throttling that starts at 012:09:34:51.537 and ends at 012:09:35:48.513 you can assume a linear ramp on the throttles; again it won't be exact.

Source: [STS-81 Mission Report](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19970016099.pdf)

Edit: From comments, here is how the Solid Rocket Booster thrust varied with time.

[image]

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_Solid_Rocket_Booster)

Comment: Thank you very much, that already solves part of the question. Is it correct that the side rocket boosters are never throttled down? Or am I missing something

Comment: They had a built-in "throttle" that made their thrust change over time. Let me see if I can find a plot of that for you.